# Python Colon operator

Tags: python

I am trying to port some Python code and I am a little lost on small issue which I would appreciate some advice.

I understand the `in` operator but I am a little unclear on what the `:` operator does in this example.

```
if foo in bar[i][:2]:
    # do something
```

In http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings it states that the `:` operator makes the first two characters only if this is a string. However when used with a list like this is that what will happen as well? So does this just mean the first 2 characters of the string in th

Comment: For a more in-depth understanding of how slices can be used via __getitem__, including Ellipsis, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called list slicing, you already link to the proper part of the documentation in your question. If you find documentation confusing, there is a video tutorial for that:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD6a0G8MnjA

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the operator doesn't depend on where its operands come from - it doesn't matter whether it was a literal, a variable, or a complex expression. The operator does its thing because its operand is a string, not because it was computed in a particular way.